# NSOutlineView Sidebar help

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to create a simple sidebar using NSOutlineView..... how would I do this? (I'm using CoreData)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SourceView/index.html) that shows exactly how to do this. The example doesn't use Core Data but the principles are the same. There is [another sample](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/AbstractTree/) that shows how to use `NSOutlineView` with Core Data.